# Get Kth smallest element in PriorityQueue (Java)

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm doing the following problem for fun / Java practice:

> Write a method `kthSmallest` that takes in a `PriorityQueue` of integers as input and outputs the `kth` smallest integer. **The internal state of the priority queue passed in should not be  changed by the method**. You may use ONLY one queue or stack as extra data. No other data structures allowed. `k` is 1-indexed (`k = 1` means the smallest value).

Getting the `kth` element is simple: just remove `k` times since it's a priority queue. I figured that I could just pop off, put the elements on a stack for storage, and then add them back to the queue once I'm done. That doesn't work though since the elements get ordered differently in the priority queue.

Here's my code for curiosity:

```
public int kthSmallest(PriorityQueue<Integer> pq, int k) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
            s.push(pq.remove());
    }

    int kthValue = s.peek();

    while (!s.empty()) {
        pq.add(s.pop());
    }

    return kthValue;
}
```

So how can I do this while maintaining the internal state of the priority queue?

P.S. - You can view the problem yourself [here](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+18&problem=bjp3-18-e9-kthSmallest)

Comment: Are you sure the exact internal state matters? No externally visible properties of the priority queue are different at the end. That sounds unchanged enough to me.

Comment: Yeah :/  It's an online simulator and it fails if the internal state is different at all.  If you're curious: http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+18&problem=bjp3-18-e9-kthSmallest

Comment: @user2357112 Actually that's not true. Iteration would reveal differences if there are any.

Comment: @EJP The order of iteration over a priority queue is not specified.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  The internal array that stores it is in a different order, although all the PriorityQueue features working as they should.

Comment: I really don't think that's the problem. After all, the `PriorityQueue` is free to do whatever it wants to its internal state, even start a new thread and mess with its innards while you're doing something completely unrelated, as long as it provides the operations it documents with the invariants it documents.

Comment: Run my code through this simulator and you'll see that it doesn't like the order of the internal array: http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+18&problem=bjp3-18-e9-kthSmallest

Comment: We can't access the simulator. It requires a login.

Comment: @user2357112 My bad!  Just fixed the link

Comment: @arshajii I'm aware of that. It doesn't alter the truth of my comment. The difference *has* been observed *somehow.*

Comment: sorry, deleted the answer, since i think it was just a stupid. now i solved the problem and in fact your problem is a mix of the priority in the given queue, like stated in the answer of Visionary Software Solution (the queue is not sorted like you would sort integers) and your stack. to solve it, i used a priority queue as a buffer without any stupid comparator and just iterated over the buffer instead of the given queue. i don't know if you want the solution directly (imho the one of Visionary Software Solutions is invalid, dunno)

Comment: @EJP A difference in iteration order does not necessarily imply a change in the internal state (or, at least, that cannot be inferred given the way in which a `PriorityQueue` is specified). What if, for instance, everything is put into an array, shuffled, and an iterator over that array is returned?

Answer (score 2):

You can't guarantee anything about the underlying state: the only concept of order that a `PriorityQueue` has is the one provided by the `Comparator` you specify when creating it (or the natural ordering of its elements). You as the user know nothing beyond that, and it really shouldn't make any difference *how* the elements are stored so as long as the behavior of the queue is in accordance with what is expected based on its specification.

Comment: This simulator demands that the internal state is not changed.  That's why my code is failing.  Check it yourself if you're curious: http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+18&problem=bjp3-18-e9-kthSmallest

Comment: @CaseyPatton That's an odd constraint, but one thing you could try is creating a copy via `PriorityQueue`s [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.PriorityQueue)), and work with the copy instead. i.e. just add `pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(pq)` at the start.

Comment: I agree it's a weird constraint.  That's a simple solution, but the problem definition specifies that "You may use one queue or stack as extra data", and an extra priority queue is not allowed.

Comment: @CaseyPatton You don't need to store the elements you pull off the queue anymore; you're working with a copy, so you don't need the `Stack`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a copy though because that uses storage.  The problem constrains the extra data allowed strictly to primitives, and one stack or queue.

Comment: Maybe this problem's just messed up?  I mean, one solution I could think of is to just access the internal array of the priority queue and then iterate through the array k times (via recursion) and return that value.  I SERIOUSLY doubt that's what the problem writer had in mind, though haha.

Comment: Wouldn't that modify the internal state of the array?  It's not guaranteed that the internal state of a PriorityQueue array is ordered, is it?

Comment: @CaseyPatton Yes, I meant a copy, but perhaps that's not allowed either.

Comment: You can actually iterate over the `PriorityQueue`, so you don't need to reach into the internals. However, I'd just abandon the problem. The requirements are unreasonable, and it teaches you to worry about things that are actively harmful to worry about.

Comment: You're probably right.  I just e-mailed the creator of the problem letting him know.  On to the next!

Comment: @CaseyPatton in fact, the solution makes you worry about things: calling methods on classes you get by API, where don't have control or knowledge on the behaviour (like the ugly comparator in this case). in this case, you poll and add the object without knowing how it is impacted with the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you removing? There's no need to modify the passed in data structure, and that's why your algorithm is failing. This is nothing more than an [ITERATOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator)/[VISITOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). All you need to do is traverse the queue and maintain a list/array of smallest numbers.

Also note that your assumption that the kth smallest integer in the queue is the same as the numbers removed in priority is not necessarily correct. A priority queue != heap. In this instance, I may have a Priority Queue of integers, each of which has a priority field.

```
class Node<Integer>
   Integer data;
   int priority;
}

class PriorityQueue {
   List<Node> nodes;

   Integer getHighestPriority() { 
      int maxPriorityIndex = 0;
      for(int i=0; i< nodes.size(); i++) {
      if(n.priority > maxPriority) {
           maxPriorityIndex = nodes.get(i);
      }
      return nodes.get(maxPriorityIndex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more detail on this solution?  Finding the k-th smallest element would take "k" traversals (we can't assume the underlying collection is sorted, right?).  Doing k traversals would require recursion....and I'm doubting that's what this problem was shooting for, though I realize it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

many hints have been stated, i'll keep my answer short:

you are working with method calls from the given object, that you don't have any knowledge from. you don't know if a weird comparator is used, to compare the integers inside the queue (e.g. a comparator that says, all things are equal and will always return 0). that's why you should in no case, modify the given object (like you do with poll/add).

in this case, to workaround this, you can use a buffer object (like stated in the question, a queue or a stack (i used a queue like the given one) to use a comparator of your choice and buffer it by adding your given queue to the buffer object.

[my solution at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Usfp699Q) since i don't have any spoiler tags :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class KthLargest {

// 20 10 60 30 50 40
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int a[]= {20, 10, 60, 30, 50, 40};
    int k = 3;
    
    int largest = priorityQueueLargest(a, k);
    
    int smallest = priorityQueueSmallest(a, k);
    
    System.out.println(k+" th largest ="+largest);
    
    System.out.println(k+" th smallest ="+smallest);
}

public static int priorityQueueLargest(int a[], int k) {
    
    PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        priorityQueue.add(a[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=k; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(priorityQueue.peek() < a[i]) {
            priorityQueue.poll();
            priorityQueue.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return priorityQueue.peek();
}

public static int priorityQueueSmallest(int a[], int k) {
    
    PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        priorityQueue.add(a[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=k; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(priorityQueue.peek() > a[i]) {
            priorityQueue.poll();
            priorityQueue.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return priorityQueue.peek();
    
}

}
```